# Extract version of python wheel at runtime

Tags: python, azure-devops, python-wheel

I'm currently working on a project in which we are using AzureDevOps pipeline to publish a wheel file into azure artifacts.
During the Pipeline I'm setting a version tag which will be written in a file called "deploymentversion"

The content of this file will be read from my setup.py and setting the version when building the wheel file.

After installing the wheel on my machine, i want to have kind like a help() function like this.

```
import myWhlPackage
myWhlPackage.help()
```

This help()-function inside my code should just print out some constant text and the current installed version of the wheel. So if i do another release, this version tag should be also increased based on the installed version of the wheel.

i've tried to provide the deploymentversion file also with the whl file, but after installation it is not possible to read from that.

Any suggestions what kind of workflow will be the best? Haven't found any similiar usecase.

Deployment will be fixed for AzureDevOps.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try using getversion to extract version of python wheel at runtime. Click [this document](https://smarie.github.io/python-getversion/) for detailed information.

According to the document:

> At runtime (when you need that version number), packages and modules
> can be
>
> - already imported or not
> - built and pip-installed (in debug mode or not), or simply added to    the PYTHON PATH (sys.path)
> - non-built and added to the PYTHON PATH (sys.path)
>
> This variety of settings makes it very difficult for existing
> solutions to tackle all aspects of this problem. pkg_resources is
> probably the best way to get it as of today (like this), but does not
> work for example when a package is an unzipped wheel added to the
> PYTHON PATH. It also does not support built-in modules.